# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen When installing gems wtih native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-14.04, bundler

When I do

```
bundle install
```

on my ubuntu server. I get a permission error for all gems that uses native extensions. Like this one.

```
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/vhosts/my_application/httpdocs/my_application/gems/gems/json-1.8.3/tests/test_json.rb
```

I have installed ruby 2.2.1 with rvm and I have a local gemset for this user.

I am guessing that it might be a problem regarding the users permissions, but I don't know how to fix it.

There could also be something I need to install. Like ruby-dev?

Here are some info from the server.

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1-dev [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

bundler --version
Bundler version 1.11.2
```

Thanks!